# How to know if a package is installed in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux

I am creating an alarm clock for my project in C. I am using mgp123 command(in package mpg321) to run the alarm sound. It is only for UBUNTU users.I need the program to check whether mpg321 is installed or not. How can i find using C if the package mpg321 is installed using C program?

Comment: If your target is Ubuntu just distribute your application as a `.deb` package and put `mpg321` as a dependency.

Comment: Use auto tools on Linux?

Comment: Actually i have to submit it with C extension only.So i have to do it in the program itself

Comment: @gongzhitaao the autotools checks in the compilation phase and not in the running phase. the program could installed via package and not build  before the installation

Comment: See: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: I think for most C extensions, most authurs don't even care about dependencies... But yes it is a good practice to generate some error to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `system()`

```
system("mpg321 -h");
```

if the command return error than the `mpg321` is not installed

Comment: how will i let c program know that an error has been returned?

Comment: Check the return value of the `system` call, e.g. `int result = system("mpg321 -h");`. If `result` is 0, then everything is OK.

Comment: ohk..it works..Is there anyway to hide the help menu from appearing in the terminal?

Comment: @SudoReboot "mpg321 -h 1>/dev/null"

Comment: @SudoReboot: Yes, just do `system("mpg321 -h >/dev/null 2>&1");`